# How to output PHP built-in web server logs to stdout?

Tags: php, python, logging, webserver

Is it possible to make a PHP's built-in web server instance send the errors and access log (only for that specific process) to `/dev/stderr`, `/dev/stdout` or a file, as in [python's built-in web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064577/how-to-use-simplehttpserver)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved this by doing `php -S 127.0.0.1:80 2>&1 >/dev/null > ./my-log-file.log`

`php -S 127.0.0.1:80 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep blablabla` also works